# How do I set vscode launch.json to debug java and cucumber?

Tags: java, cucumber, vscode-debugger

Goodmorinig,
I developed the Test Automation with java, maven , cucumber and selenium.
I would like run and debug this test with vscode.
How do I set launch.json to run/debug java and test cucumber ?

Thank you very much

I write the launch.json in the following way :

```
{
    "configurations": [

    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch with Arguments Prompt",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main",
        "args": [
            "src/test/resources/features/featuresDevelopment/esselunga/cassaAssistita/cassaStandard/BasketsWithFidatyShoppingCoupon.feature",
        ],
        "vmArgs": "-DfrontEnd=true -DdriverUpAuto=true -Dheadless=true -DrestoreCashDesk=false -DenableCheckReceipt=true -DexecutionMode=pipeline",
    }
    ]
}
```

But the system send me the following message : You can implement missing steps with the snippets below.